# rendering both authenticated and non authenticated conditional stack navigator, after setting redux state

Tags: react-native, redux, expo, react-navigation, asyncstorage

i am trying to conditionally render authenticated and unauthenticated screens based on "isAuthenticated" state redux value (trying to achieve exactly as mentioned in this link:

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/?fbclid=IwAR3Wj664kuFR32LJ4CjCkofyv3L1cjDRIc-JFbNICddY6JLqgX-wdGiG8Ls

**Current flow of my app is:**

1. User sees unauthenticated link (signup page),
2. Once user signs up "isAuthenticated" redux state value is changed to true from false and token is locally saved using AsyncStorage
3. Every time app is closed and reopened, action is used to read local data and isAuthenticated is set to true.

**Problem:**

Every time app is opened for split second non authenticated screen is shown and then authenticated screen is shown.

**Desired result:**

Either Authenticated screen or non authenticated screen should be shown, according to isAuthenticated boolean value.

**Cause of Problem identified:**

As "isAuthenticated" default value is set to false, every time app starts, for split second isAuthenticated will be false and non authenticated screen will be shown for few second.

During that same time, local AsyncStorage data is read and redux state value is changed to true, that results in another re-renders and shows authenticated screen.

As isAuthenticated has both false and true value during re opening of app, any suggestion to solve this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> As "isAuthenticated" default value is set to false, every time app starts, for split second isAuthenticated will be false and non authenticated screen will be shown for few second.

The problem is that this cannot be represented in `true` and `false`, since there are actually 3 states:

1. checking
2. checked, logged in
3. checked, not logged in

The easiest way would be to add another state property "checkingAuthentication" or whatever you prefer, and show a splash screen until you finish checking. The example in docs do this with a `isLoading` state.